# add endeavouros loading to other distro

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I recently tried out EndeavourOS on my laptop and noticed it had a cool custom pacman animation. After it using for a bit I noticed it popping up in some apps that weren't made specifically for EndeavourOS (yay for instance).
Is this some kind of system-wide thing I can make a custom version of, or at least move to normal arch?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what EndeavourOS is, but it sounds like they just enable pacman's `ILoveCandy` option out of the box.